# Link to shared library from Android library project with ndk-build

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

I have an Android library project 'A', which contains native C++ sources in the 'A/jni' folder which nicely build to a 'A/libs/armeabi-v7a/libA.so' and related for other platforms.

I now want to make an Android project 'B' which consists of Java stuff as well as more native C++ sources in the 'B/jni' folder. These sources use code from the C++ library of project 'A'. I have managed to compile these fine by setting my

```
  LOCAL_C_INCLUDES  := (path_to_A/jni)
```

(i.e. this picks up the header files from project 'A').

The question: how do I link to 'A/lib/armeabi-v7a/libA.so' in a clean way?

I have read the IMPORT_MODULE documentation, but that seems to be geared towards a situation in which you want to link to a pure-NDK module, not a library which sits inside an Android library project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a module that will compile your libA.so library as prebuilt shared library in your project B.

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libA
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := path/to/libA.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Then, add this module to your main module of your project by:

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libA
```

I have never tried IMPORT_MODULE option in my project but this works in my case.

Comment: Just to complete this answer: in order for this to work, the environment variable NDK_MODULE_PATH needs to contain the location of the libA top level folder, and you need to add $(call import-module, libA) to the end of Android.mk for project B.

Answer (score 0):

@Kasper: you say:

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES  := (path_to_B/jni)
```

Did you mean:

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES  := (path_to_A/jni)
```

?

Comment: Yes, sorry, now fixed.